# CheckBox in a row of ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick, onitemclicklistener

How do I override a CheckBox's default `onClick()` behaviour?

**Use case** I want the checkBox to reflect some boolean status of the object being rendered in the row view. When the user clicks on the row (including the checkBox), some process will run which may alter the objects state (the boolean variable).

Now how do I prevent the CheckBox's default onClick behaviour from kicking in? In other words I want `CheckBox.onClick()` to call `theCustomAdapter.onItemClick()`. How do I achieve this?

On a second thought, is there any such widget object which just displays an on/off status & does not implement Clickable?

**Custom Adapter**

```
public class UserListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{
    private final Context context;
    private final List<User> users;

    public UserListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<User> users)
    {
        super(context, resource, users);
        this.context = context;
        this.users = users;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.user, parent, false);

//        set the loggedIn? isCurrent? radio buttons
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.isLoggedIn);
        checkBox.setChecked(users.get(position).isLoggedIn());
        checkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.isCurrent);
        checkBox.setChecked(users.get(position).isCurrent());

//        fill the user name
        TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        textView.setText(users.get(position).getUserName());

//        fill the user id
        textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.userId);
        textView.setText(users.get(position).getUserId());

//        return the row
        return row;
    }

//    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
    {
        Log.i("Clicked", adapterView.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "Clicked! "+l, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Custom Row View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true">
    <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/isLoggedIn"
                 android:padding="4dp"
                android:gravity="center"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
    <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/isCurrent"
                 android:padding="4dp"
                 android:gravity="center"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/userName"
              android:padding="4dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/userId"
              android:padding="4dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i'd say if you override the `onClick()` method and provide your own implementation.

Comment: did u try this:  android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

Comment: also add android:clickable="true" in the custom row layout.

Comment: u can either override the onclick method of the checkbox or u can have android:clickable = false.

Comment: @DevZer0 How? onItemClick takes so many parameters that can't be passed through View.OnClick, if I do checkBox.setOnClickListener(this) in the Adapter class, the Adapter hs to implement View.OnClickListener which is not giving me what I want (the checkbox still toggles). So I'm clueless!

Comment: @ASP That did not solve the problem for me

Comment: did u try putting android:clickable="false" for check box and android:clickable="true" for the row parent layout which contains your checkbox.

Comment: @ASP Yes, checkBox onClick was not called, but then so was Adapters.OnIemClickListener

Comment: plz post your code snippets.....

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to CheckBoxes are Toggle Buttons:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

In the example you can see how you can make the ToggleButton decide on its own if it toggles or not, depending on whatever condition you may want to set.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've made some progress since I posted this question and I'm a sleek solution is well within the grabs. I'll keep you guys posted.