# Prevent CheckedTextView from changing check state on click

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview

I want to control the check state of my CheckedTextView programmatically and prevent it from changing on click. However, I still want to listen for and respond to click events. Here's a bit of pseudo code to illustrate my use case:

```
override fun onViewCreated() {
    val view = findViewById<CheckedTextView>(R.id.checkedTextView)

    // Check the box when the view is created, depending on state
    val checked = arguments.getBoolean("checked")
    view.isChecked = checked

    // Prompt for some additional input before actually checking the box
    view.setOnClickListener { showDialog() }
}

fun showDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setMessage("Do you really want to check the box?")
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) { _, _ -> view.isChecked = checked }
        .show()
}
```

The only way I've been able to prevent the check state from changing on click is to intercept and consume the touch event. But then I get this ugly warning:

> Custom view `CheckedTextView` has setOnTouchListener called on it but does not override performClick.

I think I can extend the view and implement the performClick method to remove the warning. Is there an easier way to accomplish my use case though?

Comment: Related but never answered: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18229239/1015595

Comment: There are 2 issues here: the technical solution and the UX side of things. Users first of all need visual feedback, besides off the dialog popping up. You could let users check the `CheckedTextView`,  show the dialog and if No is clicked, uncheck it again.